# Preg_replace not working as wanted

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Basically i have the following text stored in `$text` var :

```
$text = 'An airplane accelerates down a runway at 3.20 m/s2 for 32.8 s until is finally lifts off the ground. Determine the distance traveled before takeoff'.
```

I have a function that replaces some keywords on the text from an array named `$replacements` which is (I did a var_dump on it) :

```
'm' => string 'meter' (length=5)
'meters' => string 'meter' (length=5)
's' => string 'second' (length=6)
'seconds' => string 'second' (length=6)
'n' => string 'newton' (length=6)
'newtons' => string 'newton' (length=6)
'v' => string 'volt' (length=4)
'speed' => string 'velocity' (length=8)
'\/' => string 'per' (length=3)
's2' => string 'secondsquare' (length=12)
```

The text goes through the following function :

```
$toreplace = array_keys($replacements);

foreach ($toreplace as $r){
    $text = preg_replace("/\b$r\b/u", $replacements[$r], $text);
}
```

However, there is a difference between what I expect and the output :

```
Expected Output : an airplane accelerates down runway at 3.20 meterpersecondsquare for 32.8 second until finally lifts off ground determine distance traveled before takeoff 

Function Output : an airplane accelerates down runway at 3.20 meterpers2 for 32.8 second until finally lifts off ground determine distance traveled before takeoff
```

Notice that I expect 'meterpersecondsquare' and I get 'meterpers2' (the 's2' isn't replaced) while the 'm' and '/' were replaced with their values.

I noticed that when I put m/s instead of m/s2 it works fine and gives :

```
an airplane accelerates down runway at 3.20 meterpersecond for 32.8 second until finally lifts off ground determine distance traveled before takeoff
```

So the problem is basically it doesn't match that s2. Any thoughts why is it the case?

Comment: Move the `s2` replacement before the `s` replacement.

Comment: This works however makes the 's' alone fail

Comment: That's a little odd.  What is the exact output?  It sounds as if your last element in the replacements array is not being executed.

Comment: for m/s2 it is working, however for m/s it gives meterpers

Comment: @FaouziNikolaic Shouldn't `$text` be using double quotes, instead of single quotes, or does it not matter in this case? Such as `$text="string";` *Just saying*.

Comment: @Fred for php it's not a problem if you use single or double quotes, the problem was on the ordering of the replacement array as statement on the answer.

Comment: @FaouziNikolaic Ah, ok. Just thought I'd ask/point that out. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `s2` replacement before the `s` replacement.

Since you are doing the replacement one at a time, you are destroying the `s2` before it gets a chance to replace it.

**3.20 m/s2** will be transformed like this

> [m] 3.20 meter/s2
>
> [s] 3.20 meter/second2
>
> [/] 3.20 meterpersecond2

Which results in **meterpersecond2**

## Here is the proper order

```
'm' => string 'meter' (length=5)
'meters' => string 'meter' (length=5)
's2' => string 'secondsquare' (length=12)
's' => string 'second' (length=6)
'seconds' => string 'second' (length=6)
'n' => string 'newton' (length=6)
'newtons' => string 'newton' (length=6)
'v' => string 'volt' (length=4)
'speed' => string 'velocity' (length=8)
'\/' => string 'per' (length=3)
```

Comment: actually is mentioned on the commment, if moved the s2 works well and gives meterpersecondsquare, however for m/s it doesn't work anymore and gives meterpers, i tried changing the replacements var from s2->secondsquare to second2-> secondsquare following the final output, but not working too...

Comment: @FaouziNikolaic, I updated the correct order.  The reason your other change didn't work is because the string would be transformed from `m/s` to `meters/s` to `meterspers` which disqualifies `s` since it is no longer alone if left at the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot that ordered made everything work properly ! (moral of the question order is always important)